# Magento data array storage in custom session object

Tags: php, magento, session, magento-1.9

I am using my own session class, in that class, I am using some protected data members and some public data methods While I storing some variable on my session class Like

```
Mage::getSingleton('decision/session')->storeProductInfo('2');
```

Here is function implementation, `$this->_productId` is the private data member of my session class.

```
Public function storeProductInfo($product_id){
    $this->_productId = $product_id;
    return $this;
}
```

I am getting the stored variable by calling the below statement, it return me "**null**".

```
$product_stored_id = Mage::getSingleton('decision/session')->getStoredProductInfo();

public function getStoredProductInfo(){
   return $this->_productId;
}
```

Even

```
Mage:getSingleton('decision/session')->setData('product_id', '2');
```

Didn't working. Can you please let me know where I am going wrong? I have to store some arrays in my session that's why I created my own session class to separately deal with my logic.

Answer (score 1):

Use Magento Magic Method get and set

For that when your observer will call then you can create the session and set the value of that.

you can set the session using set, getting value using get and unset session using uns.

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMySessionVariable('MyValue'); 

$myValue = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMySessionVariable();

echo $myValue;
```

To Unset the session

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsMySessionVariable();


$inputMessage = 'Hello World';
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setWelcomeMessage($inputMessage);
```

Now you want to echo the "welcome message" somewhere else in your code/site.

```
$outputMessage = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getWelcomeMessage();
echo $this->__($outputMessage);
```

Comment: ok, Yes i know about core/session but i am little confuse about on what cases we have to define our session objects?

Comment: if you want to store temporary value and you want to store it after some event occure than we'll use session value.

Comment: For example i save product delivery date in session variable and i want to post after order complete than we'll store value in frontend session.Keep in mind front-end and back-end both session are different.

Comment: ok, Can we store full objects  and arrays in session variables?